# Easy way to calculate discriminant

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to calculate the discriminant of of ring of integers with integral basis $$1,\sqrt{p}, \frac{1+\sqrt{pq}}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q}}{2}$$
The standard definition is to look at the matrix with entries $\sigma_i(\alpha_j)$ and then take the square of the determinant. However that would seem to involve taking the determinant of a $4$x$4$ matrix which is very ugly. Is there a quicker way of doing this?

Comment: Are you sure that it would be ugly even after you started a Gauss-elimination, in a tricky row order?

Comment: Taking the traces of products may be cleaner.

Comment: Use the *Fuhrerdiskriminantelformel*?

Comment: Ugh, those words make me queasy.

Comment: It translates literally "leading/controlling discriminant formula" on English, I don't know what it means. It might be a German terminology which is known even in English environment (like the "eigenvalue").

Comment: If those numbers are $s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4$, in that order, then the matrix $A=(tr(s_is_j))_{1\le i,j\le4}$ takes the simple form
$$A=\pmatrix{4&0&2&0\cr0&4p&0&2p\cr 2&0&1+pq&0\cr0&2p&0&p+q\cr}.$$ We easily see that $\det A=16p^2q^2$, so the discriminant is $\pm 4pq$.

Comment: I think perhaps it should be *Fueherdiskriminantelproduktformel*....

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, you didn’t want to take square root, did you?